# Convert URLSearchParams to HttpParams - Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am trying to update the Http to HttpClient from a service.ts on Angular8.

I have changed the Http and Headers for HttpClient and HttpHeaders and I have deleted the '.pipe(map((response) => response.json().response));'. The options search:params.toString() wasn't work on HttpParams and as recommended I have changed to params only.

But the requests are not working as they should :(

Before (Http)

```js
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Http, Headers, Jsonp } from '@angular/http';
import { Environment } from '../app.component';
//my components imports

@Injectable()
export class CompanyService implements OnDestroy {
    private url = Environment.origin;
    private urlMainSearch = Environment.MAIN_SEARCH;
    private urlSearchAll = Environment.SEARCH_ALL;
    private headers = new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/cp+json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    private headersFile = new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/cp+json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=something'
    });
    constructor(private http: Http,
        private jsonp: Jsonp) { }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        delete this.http;
    }

    buscarEmpresas(pesquisa: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/${pesquisa}/search`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json().response));
    }

    buscarEmpresasCache(pesquisa: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/search?texto=${StringUtils.unaccent(pesquisa)}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json().response));
    }

    buscarEmpresasMicroServico(pesquisa: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.urlMainSearch}/main-search?texto=${StringUtils.unaccent(pesquisa)}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json().response));
    }

    getEmpresa(id: number): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/${id}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }

    getEmpresaByUrlLink(urlLink: string): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/link/${urlLink}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }

    getEmpresaRatings(id: number): Observable<Retorno<Rating>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/${id}/ratings`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Rating>(response.json())));
    }

    getOperadora(): Observable<Array<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/search/operadora/10/1`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json().map(empresa => new Empresa(empresa))));
    }

    getTopEmpresas(type: number): Observable<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/top?type=${type}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<Empresa>>(response.json())));
    }

    buscarEmpresasPorTipo(tipo: number, pagina: number, tags: Array<number>, continentes: Array<number>,
        paises: Array<number>, cidades: Array<number>): Observable<Retorno<Array<EmpresaRating>>> {

        // if(!this.resolveUrlSearchBug()) {
        let url = `${this.url}/companies/searchtype?number=25&page=${pagina}&type=${tipo}`;
        if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
            const tag = `&tags=${tags.join(',')}`;
            url = url + tag;
        }
        if (continentes && continentes.length > 0) {
            const continente = `&continentes=${continentes.join(',')}`;
            url = url + continente;
        }
        if (paises && paises.length > 0) {
            const pais = `&paises=${paises.join(',')}`;
            url = url + pais;
        }
        if (cidades && cidades.length > 0) {
            const cidade = `&cidades=${cidades.join(',')}`;
            url = url + cidade;
        }
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<EmpresaRating>>(response.json())));
        // }
    }

    buscarTodasEmpresas(pagina: number, texto: string, tipos: Array<number>, tags: Array<number>, localizacoes: Array<number>):
    Observable<Retorno<RankingTodasEmpresas>> {

        let url = `${this.urlSearchAll}/company-search-all?texto=${texto}&limit=25&offset=${pagina}`;
        if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
            const tag = `&tags=${tags.join(',')}`;
            url = url + tag;
        }
        if (localizacoes && localizacoes.length > 0) {
            const localizacao = `&localizacoes=${localizacoes.join(',')}`;
            url = url + localizacao;
        }
        if (tipos && tipos.length > 0) {
            const tipo = `&tipos=${tipos.join(',')}`;
            url = url + tipo;
        }
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<RankingTodasEmpresas>(response.json())));
    }

    buscarEmpresasSimilares(tipo: number, idEmpresaPesquisada: number): Observable<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/random-searchtype?type=${tipo}&idEmpresaPesquisada=${idEmpresaPesquisada}`,
            { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<Empresa>>(response.json())));
    }

    buscarMenuTags(tipo: number): Observable<Retorno<SuperMenu>> {
        // console.log(this.resolveUrlSearchBug());
        // if(!this.resolveUrlSearchBug()) {
        // console.log('Chamando service.........');
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/searchtype/filtro?type=${tipo}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<SuperMenu>(response.json())));
        // }
    }

    cadastrarEmpresa(empresa: Empresa, isByCadFornecedor: boolean = false): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/companies?isByCadFornecedor=${isByCadFornecedor}`,
            JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }

    cadastrarEmpresaPreCadastro(preCadastro: EmpresaPreCadastro): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/companies/pre-cadastro`,
            JSON.stringify(preCadastro), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }

    adminCadastrarEmpresa(empresa: Empresa): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/companies/admin`, JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }

    alterarEmpresa(empresa: Empresa): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.put(`${this.url}/companies`, JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }

    buscarTiposEmpresa(): Observable<Retorno<Array<Tipo>>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/categories`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<Tipo>>(response.json())));
    }

    buscarTipoEmpresa(tipo: number): Observable<Retorno<Tipo>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/company-types/${tipo}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Tipo>(response.json())));
    }

    buscarTipoEmpresaPorUrlLink(urlLink: string): Observable<Retorno<Tipo>> {
        if (this.http) {
            return this.http.get(`${this.url}/company-types/link/${urlLink}`, { headers: this.headers })
                .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Tipo>(response.json())));
        }
    }

    atualizarStatus(codigo: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(`${this.url}/company-status`, JSON.stringify(codigo), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json()));
    }

    apagarCategoria(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/company-types/${id}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json()));
    }

    atualizarCategoria(categoria: Tipo): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(`${this.url}/company-types`, JSON.stringify(categoria), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json()));
    }

    salvarCategoria(categoria: Tipo): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put(`${this.url}/company-types`, JSON.stringify(categoria), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json()));
    }

    vincularEmpresaUser(empresa: EmpresaUsuario): Observable<Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/company-users/associar`, JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>(response.json())));
    }

    adminBuscarTodos(page: number, size: number, sort: string, approved: boolean, pending: boolean, blocked: boolean,
        denied: boolean, deleted: boolean, nome: string, tipo: number): Observable<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>> {
        const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

        params.set('page', page.toString());
        params.set('size', size.toString());
        params.set('sort', sort);

        if (approved) {
            params.set('approved', 'true');
        }

        if (pending) {
            params.set('pending', pending.toString());
        }

        if (blocked) {
            params.set('blocked', blocked.toString());
        }

        if (denied) {
            params.set('denied', denied.toString());
        }

        if (deleted) {
            params.set('deleted', deleted.toString());
        }

        if (nome) {
            params.set('nome', nome);
        }

        if (tipo) {
            params.set('typeId', tipo.toString());
        }

        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies`, { headers: this.headers, search: params.toString() })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<Empresa>>(response.json())));
    }

    deletarEmpresa(id: number): Observable<Retorno<any>> {
        return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/companies/${id}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<any>(response.json())));
    }

    uploadXLSX(file: File) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/companies/xls/`, formData, { headers: this.headersFile })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json()));
    }

    buscarEmpresaCNPJ8(cnpj: string): Observable<Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/companies/cnpj8/${cnpj}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>(response.json())));
    }

    adminBuscarEmpresasPorTipo(page: number, size: number, sort: string, tipos: Array<number>,
        id: number, nome: string): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        let t = null;
        try {
            t = tipos.join(',');
        } catch {
            t = tipos;
        }

        let url = `${this.url}/companies/buscar-tipo?page=${page}&size=${size}&sort=${sort}&tipos=${t}`;

        if (nome) {
            url = url + `&nome=${nome}`;
        }

        if (id) {
            url = url + `&id=${id}`;
        }

        return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Empresa>(response.json())));
    }

    public buscarResumoFornecedor(referencia: string): Observable<Retorno<ResumoFornecedor>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/company-dashboard/resumo/fornecedor/referencia/${referencia}`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<ResumoFornecedor>(response.json())));
    }

    public buscarResumoAgencia(): Observable<Retorno<ResumoAgencia>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/company-dashboard/resumo/agencia`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<ResumoAgencia>(response.json())));
    }

    public buscarBarraCamposPreenchidos(): Observable<Retorno<number>> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/company-dashboard/barra-campos`, { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<number>(response.json())));
    }

    public salvarLocalizacoes(id: number, locais: Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>):
        Observable<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/company-localizacao/salvar/${id}`, JSON.stringify(locais), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>(response.json())));
    }

    public removerLocalizacao(id: number, local: ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp):
        Observable<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/company-localizacao/remover/${id}`, JSON.stringify(local), { headers: this.headers })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>(response.json())));
    }

    public adminBuscarLocalizacoes(page: number, size: number, sort: string): Observable<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>> {
        const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('page', page.toString());
        params.set('size', size.toString());
        params.set('sort', sort);

        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/company-localizacao/admin-filtrar`, { headers: this.headers, search: params.toString() })
            .pipe(map((response) => new Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>(response.json())));
    }

    public buscarLocalizacoes(texto: string): Observable<any> {
        const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('texto', texto.toString());
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/company-localizacao`, { headers: this.headers, search: params.toString() })
            .pipe(map((response) => response.json().response));
    }

    private resolveUrlSearchBug(): boolean {
        const url = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        if (url[1] !== 'empresas') {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

After (HttpClient)

```js
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Environment } from '../app.component';
//my components imports


@Injectable()
export class CompanyService implements OnDestroy {
    private url = Environment.origin;
    private urlMainSearch = Environment.MAIN_SEARCH;
    private urlSearchAll = Environment.SEARCH_ALL;
    private headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/cp+json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    private headersFile = new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/cp+json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=something'
    });
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        delete this.http;
    }

    buscarEmpresas(pesquisa: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/companies/${pesquisa}/search`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarEmpresasCache(pesquisa: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/companies/search?texto=${StringUtils.unaccent(pesquisa)}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarEmpresasMicroServico(pesquisa: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.urlMainSearch}/main-search?texto=${StringUtils.unaccent(pesquisa)}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    getEmpresa(id: number): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies/${id}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    getEmpresaByUrlLink(urlLink: string): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies/link/${urlLink}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    getEmpresaRatings(id: number): Observable<Retorno<Rating>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Rating>>(`${this.url}/companies/${id}/ratings`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    getOperadora(): Observable<Array<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.get<Array<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies/search/operadora/10/1`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    getTopEmpresas(type: number): Observable<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>>(`${this.url}/companies/top?type=${type}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarEmpresasPorTipo(tipo: number, pagina: number, tags: Array<number>, continentes: Array<number>,
        paises: Array<number>, cidades: Array<number>): Observable<Retorno<Array<EmpresaRating>>> {

        // if(!this.resolveUrlSearchBug()) {
        let url = `${this.url}/companies/searchtype?number=25&page=${pagina}&type=${tipo}`;
        if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
            const tag = `&tags=${tags.join(',')}`;
            url = url + tag;
        }
        if (continentes && continentes.length > 0) {
            const continente = `&continentes=${continentes.join(',')}`;
            url = url + continente;
        }
        if (paises && paises.length > 0) {
            const pais = `&paises=${paises.join(',')}`;
            url = url + pais;
        }
        if (cidades && cidades.length > 0) {
            const cidade = `&cidades=${cidades.join(',')}`;
            url = url + cidade;
        }
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Array<EmpresaRating>>>(url, { headers: this.headers })
        // }
    }

    buscarTodasEmpresas(pagina: number, texto: string, tipos: Array<number>, tags: Array<number>, localizacoes: Array<number>):
    Observable<Retorno<RankingTodasEmpresas>> {

        let url = `${this.urlSearchAll}/company-search-all?texto=${texto}&limit=25&offset=${pagina}`;
        if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
            const tag = `&tags=${tags.join(',')}`;
            url = url + tag;
        }
        if (localizacoes && localizacoes.length > 0) {
            const localizacao = `&localizacoes=${localizacoes.join(',')}`;
            url = url + localizacao;
        }
        if (tipos && tipos.length > 0) {
            const tipo = `&tipos=${tipos.join(',')}`;
            url = url + tipo;
        }
        return this.http.get<Retorno<RankingTodasEmpresas>>(url, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarEmpresasSimilares(tipo: number, idEmpresaPesquisada: number): Observable<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>>(`${this.url}/companies/random-searchtype?type=${tipo}&idEmpresaPesquisada=${idEmpresaPesquisada}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarMenuTags(tipo: number): Observable<Retorno<SuperMenu>> {
        // console.log(this.resolveUrlSearchBug());
        // if(!this.resolveUrlSearchBug()) {
        // console.log('Chamando service.........');
        return this.http.get<Retorno<SuperMenu>>(`${this.url}/companies/searchtype/filtro?type=${tipo}`, { headers: this.headers })
        // }
    }

    cadastrarEmpresa(empresa: Empresa, isByCadFornecedor: boolean = false): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.post<Retorno<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies?isByCadFornecedor=${isByCadFornecedor}`,
            JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    cadastrarEmpresaPreCadastro(preCadastro: EmpresaPreCadastro): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.post<Retorno<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies/pre-cadastro`,
            JSON.stringify(preCadastro), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    adminCadastrarEmpresa(empresa: Empresa): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.post<Retorno<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies/admin`, JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    alterarEmpresa(empresa: Empresa): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        return this.http.put<Retorno<Empresa>>(`${this.url}/companies`, JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarTiposEmpresa(): Observable<Retorno<Array<Tipo>>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Array<Tipo>>>(`${this.url}/categories`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarTipoEmpresa(tipo: number): Observable<Retorno<Tipo>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<Tipo>>(`${this.url}/company-types/${tipo}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    buscarTipoEmpresaPorUrlLink(urlLink: string): Observable<Retorno<Tipo>> {
        if (this.http) {
            return this.http.get<Retorno<Tipo>>(`${this.url}/company-types/link/${urlLink}`, { headers: this.headers })
        }
    }

    atualizarStatus(codigo: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put<any>(`${this.url}/company-status`, JSON.stringify(codigo), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    apagarCategoria(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.url}/company-types/${id}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    atualizarCategoria(categoria: Tipo): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put<any>(`${this.url}/company-types`, JSON.stringify(categoria), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    salvarCategoria(categoria: Tipo): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.put<any>(`${this.url}/company-types`, JSON.stringify(categoria), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    vincularEmpresaUser(empresa: EmpresaUsuario): Observable<Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>> {
        return this.http.post<Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>>(`${this.url}/company-users/associar`, JSON.stringify(empresa), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    adminBuscarTodos(page: number, size: number, sort: string, approved: boolean, pending: boolean, blocked: boolean,
        denied: boolean, deleted: boolean, nome: string, tipo: number): Observable<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>> {
        const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

        params.set('page', page.toString());
        params.set('size', size.toString());
        params.set('sort', sort);

        if (approved) {
            params.set('approved', 'true');
        }

        if (pending) {
            params.set('pending', pending.toString());
        }

        if (blocked) {
            params.set('blocked', blocked.toString());
        }

        if (denied) {
            params.set('denied', denied.toString());
        }

        if (deleted) {
            params.set('deleted', deleted.toString());
        }

        if (nome) {
            params.set('nome', nome);
        }

        if (tipo) {
            params.set('typeId', tipo.toString());
        }

        return this.http.get<Retorno<Array<Empresa>>>(`${this.url}/companies`, { headers: this.headers, params })
    }

    deletarEmpresa(id: number): Observable<Retorno<any>> {
        return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.url}/companies/${id}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    uploadXLSX(file: File) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/companies/xls/`, formData, { headers: this.headersFile })
    }

    buscarEmpresaCNPJ8(cnpj: string): Observable<Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<EmpresaUsuario>>(`${this.url}/companies/cnpj8/${cnpj}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    adminBuscarEmpresasPorTipo(page: number, size: number, sort: string, tipos: Array<number>,
        id: number, nome: string): Observable<Retorno<Empresa>> {
        let t = null;
        try {
            t = tipos.join(',');
        } catch {
            t = tipos;
        }

        let url = `${this.url}/companies/buscar-tipo?page=${page}&size=${size}&sort=${sort}&tipos=${t}`;

        if (nome) {
            url = url + `&nome=${nome}`;
        }

        if (id) {
            url = url + `&id=${id}`;
        }

        return this.http.get<Retorno<Empresa>>(url, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    public buscarResumoFornecedor(referencia: string): Observable<Retorno<ResumoFornecedor>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<ResumoFornecedor>>(`${this.url}/company-dashboard/resumo/fornecedor/referencia/${referencia}`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    public buscarResumoAgencia(): Observable<Retorno<ResumoAgencia>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<ResumoAgencia>>(`${this.url}/company-dashboard/resumo/agencia`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    public buscarBarraCamposPreenchidos(): Observable<Retorno<number>> {
        return this.http.get<Retorno<number>>(`${this.url}/company-dashboard/barra-campos`, { headers: this.headers })
    }

    public salvarLocalizacoes(id: number, locais: Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>):
        Observable<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>> {
        return this.http.post<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>>(`${this.url}/company-localizacao/salvar/${id}`, JSON.stringify(locais), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    public removerLocalizacao(id: number, local: ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp):
        Observable<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>> {
        return this.http.post<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>>(`${this.url}/company-localizacao/remover/${id}`, JSON.stringify(local), { headers: this.headers })
    }

    public adminBuscarLocalizacoes(page: number, size: number, sort: string): Observable<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>> {
        const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
        params.set('page', page.toString());
        params.set('size', size.toString());
        params.set('sort', sort);

        return this.http.get<Retorno<Array<ApiLoacalizacaoCidadecp>>>(`${this.url}/company-localizacao/admin-filtrar`, { headers: this.headers, params })
    }

    public buscarLocalizacoes(texto: string): Observable<any> {
        const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
        params.set('texto', texto.toString());
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/company-localizacao`, { headers: this.headers, params })
    }

    private resolveUrlSearchBug(): boolean {
        const url = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        if (url[1] !== 'empresas') {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the variable `this.http` is of type `HttpClient`.  The type definition for `HttpClient.get()` states that the `options` argument has an optional property `params` with the type:

```
params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; };
```

It cannot be a single `string` (which is what `params.toString()` returns).  It is either a key-value object of `strings` or an `HttpParams` object.

You can just pass your `params` variable directly, since it has the type `HttpParams`.

Instead of

```
{ headers: this.headers, params: params.toString() }
```

Just do

```
{ headers: this.headers, params }
```

But isn't `params` always empty in both cases?  You initialize an empty object and don't add anything to it (unless you omitted that part).

**Edit:**

After seeing your full code I can explain what's going on with the params being empty.

On the `URLSearchParams` class, the `set()` method is a `void` method which mutates the object and returns nothing.  In the original code what they are doing is creating an empty object, setting a bunch of values on it, and then converting it to a string. (I asked the question about it being empty because the parts with `params.set()` weren't part of your example code).

```
(method) URLSearchParams.set(name: string, value: string): void

Sets the value associated to a given search parameter to the given value. If there were several values, delete the others.
```

The `HttpParams` class works differently.  Rather than updating itself with the value that you set, it returns a new instance.

```
(method) HttpParams.set(param: string, value: string): HttpParams

Replaces the value for a parameter.

@param param — The parameter name.

@param value — The new value.

@return — A new body with the new value.
```

But you aren't doing anything with the returned value since the original code was build expecting a `void` method.  You need to be changing the value of `params` to the returned value each time that you set something.  Change each `const params` to `let params` so that we can overwrite it.  Then replace all calls to `params.set()` with `params = params.set()`.  Like this:

```
let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
params = params.set('page', page.toString());
params = params.set('size', size.toString());
params = params.set('sort', sort);
```

Comment: Thanks Linda!! You are right, the type is HttpClient and params was empty (I didn't do it so I'm even more lost). I have uptaded with the whole class (it's quite large but several methods are similar). Now it is compiling but the requests are faulty.

Comment: I updated my answer for you.  Basically `UrlSearchParams` and `HttpParams` behave differently, so there are a few other changes that you need to make.

Comment: Thanks again Linda :). I realized I have to declare HttpHeaders in another way too. From what I understand from the documentation it is not so simple to make a from/to, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by from/to, but your HttpHeaders looks fine to me.

Comment: There is something wrong that I did in this update from Http to HttpClient because now it is returning 500 (on buscarBarraCamposPreenchidos() for example). If I go back as it was before it works normal.